# Any shortcut to generate a 16 byte random data as Initialisation Vector for AES128 CBC method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any easy way to generate this kind random data or string? Like an existing function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `SecRandomCopyBytes` from *Security framework*.

> This function reads from `/dev/random` to obtain an array of cryptographically-secure random bytes.

```
uint8_t vector[16];
SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 16, vector);
```

Comment: This should be preferred over `arc4random()` which only uses `/dev/urandom`, which is allowed to serve numbers with a lower randomness when the system runs low on entropy.

Comment: Indeed, +1 from me. This is the preferable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Four successive calls to `arc4random`? So something like:

```
uint32_t initialisationVector[4];
for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
    initialisationVector[c] = arc4random();

// 16 bytes of random values now sit in initialisationVector
```

Or, as per Martin R's comment, just do it in one call:

```
uint8_t initialisationVector[16];
arc4random_buf(initialisationVector, 16);
```

Comment: Or one call to arc4random_buf().

Comment: @MartinR that's a much better idea!